# How can I fix my program, it always show TypeError no matter how I change the type of the object?

Tags: python-3.x

I recently wrote a piece of code (an decryptor) to convert the result to a specific number (I took inspiration from Shamir's Secret Scheme, which uses Lagrange Polynomials as core). I previously wrote another program, which changes the secret into 'pieces', and now I stuck at converting 'pieces' into the secret again.

This is what I wrote:

```
x_values = []

y_values = []

while -1 not in x_values:

    adder = int(input('Enter x value (Enter "-1" to end): '))

    x_values.append(adder)

else:

    x_values.pop()

while len(y_values) != len(x_values):

    adder = input('Enter y value: ')

    adder = int(adder, 16)

    y_values.append(adder)

S = 0

for i in range(len(x_values)):

    x_other = x_values

    x_current = x_other.pop(i)

    y_other = y_values

    y_current = y_other.pop(i)

    num = y_values[i]

    for a in x_current:                 

        num *= -a

    den = 1

    for a in x_current:

        den *= (x_values[i] - x_current[a])

    S += (num / den)

print('Secret: ', S)

input()
```

When I run it, it shows:

```
File "C:\Python Code\Decryptor.py", line 37, in <module>
    for a in x_current:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

I have read many articles about this problem but I couldn't fix it. Could you help me with this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thank you everyone for helping me with my problem. I’ve finally managed to fix this and the program worked like a charm.

Comment: `x_current = x_other.pop(i)`: `x_current` is an integer you cannot iterate on an integer. what's so difficult to understand

Comment: Okay, I see that. I made a wrong misunderstanding on the pop method. Could you show me how to fix it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to iterate over there? What do you mean you've changed the types?

Comment: I want run through all the elements in the new list. Like list = [1, 2, 3, 4] and new_list = [2, 3, 4] (pop '1' out) and I want the variable 'a' run through all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `pop` method on a python list, it removes the entered index element from the list and then returns that element.

So `x_current` variable in first iteration is an integer with value equal to 1(In the example list: x_values = [1, 2, 3, 4]).

So the second for loop is incorrect, Because you trying to loop in an integer that is not possible. So If you want to iterate in a list that contains every elements except that has been poped, you should replace second loop with following:

```
for a in x_other:
```

Otherwise you should loop in range of `x_current`.
If you still have problems, you can leave a comment to notice me.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I changed it and it works now. So I can run x_others.pop(i) without return to a variable, right?

Comment: Yes. You can do it and then using `x_others` list without poped value.

Comment: @BinhNguyen Please remember to [accept answers that solve your problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. I didn’t realize that. Really sorry if you are annoyed